# r.js optimise require calls

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs

I have a config file with a list paths to backbone views

The config file loads via ajax and then according to which pages are specified then i have a loop running a bunch of require calls to load the files I need.

I want to run this through the grunt require optimiser and optimise all the files into a single built.js file.

All the files from the define() blocks are getting included in built.js but is there a way to specify the dynamically loaded files (from the require calls) to include in the built.js file too or do these still need to be required separately at run time?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `include` parameters of the build file. Read details [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js) (do search for "include", it can be used in a few ways).

Also check out a variation for lazy loading that is build friendly I implemented in [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy).